# How to hide parent path for specific users?

Tags: svn

We have enabled the SVNParentPath option and would like to restrict few users/groups in accessing the Parent Path. Is this possible?

**svn.conf**

```
<Location /repos>
DAV svn
SVNParentPath /var/svn/repos
AuthName "SVN Repo Authentication"
SVNListParentPath On
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /etc/svn/svn_passwd
AuthzSVNAccessfile /var/svn/repos/svn_access
Require valid-user
</Location>
```

And our access control file looks like the following

**svn_access**

```
# Groups & Users
[groups]
admin = admsvn, gurukiran

# Repo Access
[/]
@admin = rw

[groovy:/]
@admin = rw
kiran=rw
gopal=rw
ram=rw
mani=rw
vijay=rw
```

**httpd.conf**

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 80

Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

User apache
Group apache

ServerAdmin root@localhost

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>


DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types

    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>


EnableSendfile on

IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

Current Issue:

- We only need admins to have access to the SVN Parent Path. Now both admins and developers have access to the Parent Path.

Comment: The problem is that your question is missing full `httpd.conf` file and it appears that this file has some invalid directives.

Comment: Added the missing details to the original question. Do you mind taking a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should show your `httpd.conf` file. The strings you show now do not help. Second, read the [SVNBook about `mod_authz_svn`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.ref.mod_authz_svn) and see examples.

Next, make sure that you've specified the `Require valid-user` directive as well as that you specify path to `AuthzSVNAccessFile`.

BTW, this example should help: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authz.perdir.ex-3

Comment: httpd.conf is added now to the question